# Adjust layout of flexdashboard gauges in R shiny app?

Tags: css, r, shiny, flexdashboard

I am trying to generate a grid of gauges in my shiny app, however I am unsure how to adjust the layout of the gauges I am generating. Here is a reprex of my app:

```
# import libraries
library(shiny)
library(flexdashboard)
library(purrr)
library(magrittr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  # add first gauge set to ui
  fluidRow(
    uiOutput("first_gauge")),
  # add second gauge set to ui
  fluidRow(
    uiOutput("second_gauge"))
)

server <- function(input, output){
  # create first set of gauges
  output$first_gauge <- renderUI({
    # create 4 values and dynamically create gauges
    1:4 %>%
      purrr::map(flexdashboard::gauge, min = 0, max = 10)
  })
  # create second set of gauges
  output$second_gauge <- renderUI({
    # create 4 values and dynamically create gauges
    5:8 %>%
      purrr::map(flexdashboard::gauge, min = 0, max = 10)
  })
}

# run shiny app
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This app formats the 8 gauges in one long column like this:

```
gauge1
gauge2
gauge3
gauge4
gauge5
gauge6
gauge7
gauge8
```

But I am trying to format them in 2 rows of 4 like this:

```
gauge1 gauge2 gauge3 gauge4
gauge5 gauge6 gauge7 gauge8
```

I don't need the page to be fluid, it can be fixed. When I have tried messing with the `column` settings in `fluidRow` or `fixedRow` the gauges don't seem to move.

I have been experimenting with using `includeCSS` and messing with these margins, but I know little CSS and this doesn't seem to modify the margins *between* gauges:

```
.html-widget.gauge svg {
  height: 40%; 
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this

```r
# import libraries
library(shiny)
library(flexdashboard)
library(purrr)
library(magrittr)

ui <- fluidPage(
    # add first gauge set to ui
    fluidRow(
        uiOutput("first_gauge")),
    # add second gauge set to ui
    fluidRow(
        uiOutput("second_gauge")),
    tags$style(".gauge.html-widget {display: inline-block;}"),
)

server <- function(input, output){
    # create first set of gauges
    output$first_gauge <- renderUI({
        # create 4 values and dynamically create gauges
        tagList(
            1:4 %>%
                purrr::map(flexdashboard::gauge, min = 0, max = 10),
            tags$script("$('.gauge.html-widget').css({height: '100px', width: '22%'})")
        )
    })
    # create second set of gauges
    output$second_gauge <- renderUI({
        # create 4 values and dynamically create gauges
        tagList(
            5:8 %>%
                purrr::map(flexdashboard::gauge, min = 0, max = 10),
            tags$script("$('.gauge.html-widget').css({height: '100px', width: '22%'})")
        )
    })
}

# run shiny app
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

- We first need to change the gauge display from `block` (default) to `inline-block` so they can be displayed in the same row. `block` means the current element take up all width of current row, so we need to change it. To change this, we can simply add a `style` tag.
- Default `flexdashboard::gauge` takes a lot of height and width, however the R function doesn't provide us any argument to change the default height and width, and it uses `style="xxx"` for the CSS later on HTML, which has the highest priority. Adding `style` tag will not do the work. We need to use javascript change this. Since the gauge is dynamically rendered from server, the script also needs to be added on server.
- To display 4 gauge per row, each one of them takes 25% of the width, but there is some padding added in the original style, so we can't use exact 25, must be smaller than this number. Here 22 is used, change it to a reasonable number you want.
  [image]